# Execute script (or git command) post git merge | Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, githooks

I need to execute a script on git branch merge through bitbucket?

My requirement is to to delete the source branch from git server post merge, for this I want to execute git commands to delete the branch.

Is git hooks are the solution for same? Please suggest. Thanks

Comment: Bitbucket Cloud or Bitbucket Server?

Comment: Bitbucket Server